# Get output in a single text file_Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have two text FIles
1st one

```
id name(old File)        
1  kunal                 
2  vishal                
3  vivek                 
4  vinay
```

Second One
id name(New File-Updated)

```
1  kunal
2  vishnu
3  sumit
4  biren 
5  manish
```

Desired Output

```
1 kunal
2 vishnu
3 sumit
4 biren
5 manish
```

I need the data from both text files(in file-Second Name--The id is same but name is updated,so I need the updated one and also I need the new entries of the files -here in example id(5) in second file)

Comment: Question is unlcear.Please post your script.What should be the output?

Comment: I have also given the desired output

Comment: @vishal your 2nd file is same as Desired Output then what u want to do..

Comment: @vishalkumar As mentioned, here you could just load table 2, and you have table 3. Could you expand your example to contain all relevant cases?